# $.ajax query not posting to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've spent the better part of today trying to send a jQuery variable to my PHP file and use it in a SQL search. My first issue is that can't even get the variable into PHP properly. I am also getting an error about some of my SQL code which I've included as well.

What I want: the variable in jQuery called name sent to the PHP file where it is used in an SQL Query to find the real name of musicians. the real name would then be sent back to the HTML file where it is displayed on the webpage. MyPHPAdmin and my database has already been setup.

jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    var name = $(this).text(); 

    $('#prf').attr("class",name);
    $('#pic').attr("class",name);
    $('#info').attr("class",name);
    JSON.stringify (name);
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-name.php",
    data: {name: name}
            })
```

PHP:

```
$rname = $_POST['name']; 
var_dump($rname); 
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=myhost;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $query="SELECT realname FROM artistmaster WHERE stagename = :name";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array("name"=>$rname));    
        var_dump($rname);
        echo 'Success';            
        $result=$stmt->fetchAll();
            print "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
            print "</pre>";         
        }

        catch(PDOExeception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
NULL NULL
```

I've read the documentation on `$.ajax()` and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any help on this, it's been giving one hell of time.

Comment: PDO and mysqli are different mysql drivers in PHP. Just pick one. Also the error indicate you do not have mysqli installed, so maybe use PDO

Comment: @Fabricator Thanks, I'll switch them all over to PDO. Any ideas on the $.ajax problem?

Comment: You're not seeing data because it's not in `$_POST['data']`. See @MaggiQall's answer.

Comment: @jorg Right, I've fixed that but it's still not working. Any thoughts on the ajax syntax being incorrect maybe? I have tried putting the data: option in several different ways.

Comment: How do you get that output? I don't see anything in your code that handles the data returned from the ajax call.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I just updated my code. I added  $result=$stmt->  fetchAll();print "<pre>";print_r($result);print "</pre>" to my PHP code. The array is still empty though, it displays as Array(). I did a var_dump on the variable right after the POST, and it is still showing as NULL.

Comment: Okay, but how do you see that output on the javascript side? You have to evaluate what the AJAX request returns.

Comment: Ok how would I evaluate it then. With the success option?

Comment: Since you get the output "NULL NULL", that means the php file is called properly. How about you do an alert or console.log on _name_ to see what it is?

Comment: I have this whole jQuery function nested in a listitem.click function. That click function has to take place on my index page. When I run my index.html page I don't see the output anywhere. Do I need to add something to my jQuery code to get that output to print in a div on my index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate the output of the PHP script from the AJAX request add a return handler to your request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-name.php",
    data: {name: name}
            }).always(function( html ) {
    console.log(html); // this will show the content of the php script in the developer console of your browser
  });
```

The function defined in `.always()` is called every time an AJAX request finishes. When you made sure that your code works you can change it to `.done()`, which is only called when the AJAX call is successfull. You can also add a `.failure()` function to handle errors gracefully.

Also note this [from the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The $.ajax() function underlies all Ajax requests sent by jQuery. It is often unnecessary to directly call this function, as several higher-level alternatives like $.get() and .load() are available and are easier to use.

I'd suggest to use the `$.post` function instead:

```
$.post("ajax-name.php", {name: name}, function( html ) {
    $('#outputdiv').html(html);
    // this will replace the content of a <div id="outputdiv"></div> with the output of the AJAX request
});
```

Comment: Ok great, that cleared almost everything up for me. However, this jQuery function I'm using is nested within a click function as you can see in my code above. When that list item is clicked how can I then move the name variable returned from ajax to my index.html page?

Comment: Perfect that did it. It is acting a little strange on my front page. The text will show up, then quickly disappear. If I keep clicking too often (4-5 times) in a row it seems to lag and slow the page down significantly until I refresh the page. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Not without seeing more code. But since this is a completely different issue I suggest you open a new question for that.

Comment: Will do. Thanks a lot for the help, I was struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax-name.php",
       data: {name: name},
       success : function(html) {
        // html code, do something with it here
       }
    });
```

then

```
$rname = $_POST['name'];
$query="SELECT realname FROM artistmaster WHERE stagename = :name";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array("name"=>$rname));
```

You get your result with

```
$stmt->fetchAll();
```

You don't retrieve PDO driver results with mysqli

Comment: Got the same error. "NULL NULL Success Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result() in /home/u314991906/public_html/ajax-name.php on line 31"

Comment: Ok great, this fixed the error. However, I'm still getting NULL values when I dump the variables and there is no output from fetchAll() posted anywhere.

Comment: $result = $sth->fetchAll();

then print_r($result) to see result

Comment: Thanks for helping me out again. Unfortunately the array is still empty even with printing out the results: Array(). I just re-read the PHP documentation on the ajax function and all of the syntax seems correct. I'm stumped.

Comment: If you add $rname = 'Eminem'; // or an actual stagename you have and just run the php file. What do you get?

Comment: Ok here we go. If I add $rname = 'Avicii' in the try {} statement an array prints with Avicii's real name "Tim Bergling". So the PHP side of the document is sound. It must be something with the ajax options.

Comment: I hope the ajax code is not all you got now.

Check out Gerald Schneiders ajax function

$.post("ajax-name", {name : name}, function(html) {
 // html is now your output from the php file.
});

Answer (score 0):

alert variable name in javascript and make sure it is not null.you may use exit;
echo $_POST['name'] in the php file.receive the processed data in javascript with the success:function(result) and alert it.
store every data in a single variable in the php file. and finally echo them.